# Resharper: Is there a way to modify behaviour of Cleanup code/Update file header?

Tags: c#, resharper, code-cleanup

I used the option **Update file header** in ReSharpers' tool **Cleanup Code...** to insert copyright information, etc, in source files missing it. The **file header text** is defined like:

```
blah blah
DESCRIPTION: HeadDesc: missing file header description in $FILENAME$
copyright blah blah
```

Notice `HeadDesc: ...`: It's a custom tag definied for showing up in the *ReSharpers' To-do-Explorer*, which reminds me adding file description.

After adding a file description, the tag is removed.

**My problem:** If I re-run the *Cleanup Code...* tool, all file headers reset to the above content (that's what the tool is created for!).

**What I want:** Is there a way to configure ReSharper not to reset file headers, but checking & adding missing ones, too? If not, do you know a workaround for that purpose?

*I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and ReSharper 8.2 ...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Resharper 8.2, AFAIK.

It sounds like you are confusing the idea of a standard file header with the idea of a file template.

In your case it probably makes more sense to look at file templates, as described [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Templates__Applying_Templates__Creating_Files_from_Templates.html).

This allows you to create new files based on a template (which can have your header at the top), and you wouldn't need to do anything with the file headers/code cleanup utility.

Comment: You're right, file templates (including the header section) will be the solution to our new generated files. But I used the cleanup tool to add the header to files missing it. Maybe I won't need the cleanup tool again to check file headers, because the templates will "remind" me to fill in a meaningful description :D